# Blank/Frozen after reboot post Xenial Update

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, plymouth

I upgraded to the most recent Ubuntu package on my desktop (Dell Precision T7610) as of 10:00 am BST this morning. Everything seemed to go smoothly, however upon reboot the screen goes black and unresponsive (Just after Plymouth shows up).

I have done a bit of searching to see if a solution exists however I am not having any luck. (including https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze)

Most of the solutions seem to require an input into a terminal window/ using GRUB. I have tried opening GRUB by holding down the shift key during start up but this does not open, and I cannot get far enough to be able to open a terminal window - I am asking this question from a separate computer.

When I manually shut down (by pressing the power key), I can see a list of messages including, 'LSB failed to start up' or something similar, the messages only show for a seconds before shtting down.

Is there a way around this using the BIOS? I am new to Ubuntu and Linux operating systems, any help would be greatly appreciated.